# How do I find last monday using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I need to work with some logic that requires week begins on Monday (not Sunday).

There is a function start of week I can use:

`moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').startOf('week').add(1, 'day')`

However if its Sunday, I need to use last week's date and add 1 to get monday.

I'm hoping there is an easier to just get "last monday" no matter what the date is.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I found the answer ([documented](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/)) but there is a `isoWeek` which will start the week on Monday instead of Sunday.

Start week on Sunday:

```
moment().startOf('week');
```

Start week on Monday:

```
moment().startOf('isoWeek');
```

Comment: As its a pet peeve of mine, `.startOf('week')` should return Monday, the other call should be `.startOf('localWeek')` (or some other sillyness) Weeks start on Mondays - by international agreement - that's what the ISO is for!

Comment: `moment().startOf('week')` will also return Monday in countries (locale) that start their week with Monday.

Answer (score 8):

To find the last Monday just use

```
moment().isoWeekday(-6); // ISO day of the week with 1 being Monday and 7 being Sunday.
```

Or Locale Aware version

```
moment().weekday(-7); // when Monday is the first day of the week
```

Comment: `moment().weekday(-7)` added in 2.1.0 version

Answer (score 3):

Dunno about moment.js, but in plain javascript you can get the previous Monday by getting the day number, setting it to 7 if it's Sunday, then subtract the day number minus one from the date. If the day is Monday, it returns the same date.

e.g.

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1 - (d.getDay() || 7));
document.write(d)
```

Comment: This is really good.  However, it returns the same day if today is a Monday.  That might be desired, but the OP didn't really specify.  IMHO, if today is Monday and you ask me for "last Monday", I'll be thinking of the one 7 days ago, not the current day.

Comment: Yes, it depends on requirements. Most administrative systems I've worked with would want the same date if it was a Monday, but socially, people expect the one before. Just needs a bit more logic so if `1 - (d.getDay() || 7)` evaluates to `0`, return `-7`.

Comment: upvoted returns an arbitrary time depending on when i am querying, what do I do if I want 00 hrs 00 mins 00 secs of Monday on UTC timescale

Comment: @PirateApp—you should use `date.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)`. Presumably you're using UTC methods for everything else too (`d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate()...)`).

Answer (score 1):

```
 // when Monday is the first day of the week
moment().weekday(-7); // last Monday
```

Refer to the official docs [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/)

Comment: These examples, though in the docs, are probably not what the OP is looking for.  See [issue #2522](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2522).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to find the any day of the week before or after the current week:

```
  public static SUN = 0
  public static MON = 1
  public static TUE = 2
  public static WED = 3
  public static THU = 4
  public static FRI = 5
  public static SAT = 6

  //@return: string like Jan 30
  //@param : weekAgo number of weeks past atual wanted
  //@param : dayOfWeek number 
  //  SUN = 0
  //  MON = 1
  //  TUE = 2
  //  WED = 3
  //  THU = 4
  //  FRI = 5
  //  SAT = 6
  public static pastDayOfWeek_MMMDD(weekAgo:number, dayOfWeek:number): String {
     return moment().isoWeekday(7+((weekAgo+1)*-7)+dayOfWeek).format('MMM DD');
  }


  //@return: string like Jan 30
  //@param : weekAgo number of weeks before atual wanted
  //@param : dayOfWeek number 
  //  SUN = 0
  //  MON = 1
  //  TUE = 2
  //  WED = 3
  //  THU = 4
  //  FRI = 5
  //  SAT = 6
  public static nextDayOfWeek_MMMDD(weekBefore:number, dayOfWeek:number): String {
    return moment().isoWeekday(-7+((weekBefore+1)*7)+dayOfWeek).format('MMM DD');
  }
```